# ControlSend without WinActivate for RDP

Tags: autohotkey, windows-11

Trying to send a keystroke to RDP (mstsc.exe) in the background, without having to activate/maximize the window.

This works, but maximizes the RDP window:

```
WinActivate, ahk_exe mstsc.exe
ControlSend, , Hello World, ahk_exe mstsc.exe
```

I've found the ControlFocus function, which sounds like it should work, but the following fails (no errors, just does not send the input):

```
ControlFocus, ahk_exe mstsc.exe
ControlSend, , Hello World, ahk_exe mstsc.exe
```

Am I using ControlFocus wrong? I've tried with ahk_id and ahk_class to get control of the window, but neither work.

I've also tried with AHK V2 syntax to no avail, but am happy to use V2 if there is a working solution. Thanks!